# How to select row when drag start on Ag-grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

My grid has only 1 column.

Currently, If I enable row dragging, I'm not able to select rows, unless I bind a key to set

```
supressRowDrag=true
```

Should be possible and even simple, since the row node is already being selected somehow.
(Border gets blue after clicking.)

I want to simultaneously select and start the drag when the row is clicked.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this props to `AgGridReact` if you want the rows get selected when the drag begins.

```
onRowDragEnter={(e) => e.node.setSelected(true)}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63963503/how-to-select-row-when-drag-start-on-ag-grid-react]